# CRUD use case and relative sequence diagram

Tags: design, uml, use-case, sequence-diagram, crud

I'm building my project with Visual Paradigm and I have some use cases that implements the [CRUD pattern](http://www.se.cs.put.poznan.pl/knowledge-base/software-engineering-blog/crud-pattern-in-use-cases).

As specified in the book *Use Cases: Patterns and Blueprints*, Övergaard and Palmkvist suggest to implement a single use case as one of the best ways to handle this type of use cases. There is a different flow for each action: one operation is considered as the main flow, the others as extending flows.

The question is: considering that I'm using Visual Paradigm, which is the best way to write the relative sequence diagram of a similar use case?

Comment: Please define "best" for your case.

Comment: How can I write the sequence diagram? The correct way.

Comment: Show it to someone else and see if they understand what you’re trying to say.

Comment: It's not enough to get a "Ah yes, I understand" but when they explain what they think to see matches what you thought when creating it.

Answer (score 2):

The debate of whether covering a [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) requirement with one high-level `Manage xxx` use-case or four more detailed use-cases `Create xxx`, `Read/Retrieve xxx`,  `Update xxx`, `Delete xxx` is not new.

Alistair Cockburn, one of the signatory of the Agile Manifesto, already addressed this topic in the first edition of his book "*[Writing effective use-cases](https://www.scenarioplus.org.uk/reviews/cockburn.htm)*" in October 2000. It facilitates keeping the big picture in mind when working with the users.  But when it comes to the design and implementation, we need more details. So the level of detail of sequence diagrams may be more detailed than in the corresponding use-case.

A first remark: there is no requirement of a one-to-one mapping between use-cases and sequence diagrams.  A sequence diagram illustrates an [interaction](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/interaction.html) which is scenario based on the exchange of some messages. It does not have to be exhaustive, especially if you want to keep them readable. So if you have very different flows, the simplest way would be to make different sequence diagrams for the very different flows.  In the idea of UML fathers, the traceability is backwards (so several sequence diagrams may provide different details for the same use-case).

Now, if you managed to design your system having a common flow and seing CRUD operations as extensions, you may do it likewise for the sequences:  either with one diagram using the `alt` and `opt` [combined fragments](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams-combined-fragment.html) for the [extension points](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-extend.html#extension-point),  or with separate sequence diagram for each extension, or a combination of both.